# Python: Use array as conditions for another array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy

Is it possible to simple use an array like:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1,76,120,158,199]
```

as an condition array for another array?

I have for example an array like:

```
b=np.array([0,1,2,3,4,5,76,77,78,79,120,121,122,158,159,199,200,201])
```

All numbers of array b that are also in array a should get the number 1 for example:

**return:**

```
c=np.array([0,1,2,3,4,5,1,77,78,79,1,121,122,1,159,1,200,201])
```

So is there a fast numpy version to do this. Because the actual array is a huge 3d array with many numbers, which of course could be flattened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`numpy.in1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html) and Boolean indexing:

```
b[np.in1d(b, a)] = 1

print(b)

array([  0,   1,   2,   3,   4,   5,   1,  77,  78,  79,   1, 121, 122,
         1, 159,   1, 200, 201])
```